# DevForce Ideablade Filter on dynamic column

Tags: c#, filter, devforce

I have a complicated filter and part of it is this:

```
protected override Expression<Func<IHaveNoteRemarkSubject, bool>> MustFilterWhere()
{
    if (!Model.ExactSet) return PredicateBuilder.True<IHaveNoteRemarkSubject>();
    var mustPartsWhere = PredicateBuilder.True<IHaveNoteRemarkSubject>();

    Model.ExactFilterValue.ForEach(str => mustPartsWhere = mustPartsWhere
        .And(svi => (svi.Notes ?? string.Empty).Contains(str)));
    return mustPartsWhere;
}
```

I want to specify the field (currently "Notes") dynamically. That is, I'm going to have several filters for different fields that need this exact code and I do not want to rewrite this logic for each field individually. Reflection doesn't work because this is executed on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're already using the `PredicateBuilder` class.  That class has other helper methods that you can use to achieve fully dynamic filters.  Here is an example of a method that can bring in the property name (e.g. "Notes") and builds the filter that way:

```
private Expression<Func<IHaveNoteRemarkSubject, bool>> DynamicMustFilterWhere(IEnumerable<string> exactFilterValues, string propertyName)
{
    //Build the individual filters for each filter value
    var individualFilters =
        exactFilterValues.Select(
        //The PredicateBuilder.Make method is very handy in building dynamic filters.  In this case, we are dynamically 
        //  specifying the property name to do the Contains on
            str => PredicateBuilder.Make(typeof (IHaveNoteRemarkSubject), propertyName, FilterOperator.Contains, str));

    //AND all the individual filters together
    var combined = PredicateBuilder.And(individualFilters.ToArray<IPredicateDescription>());

    //Much of DevForce can use Predicate directly.  But if we want to end up with an Expression<Func<...>>, we can do that...

    //Have DevForce build the predicate into a lambda expression
    var lambda = combined.ToLambdaExpression();

    //Then we can cast the lambda to the Expression<Fun<...>> type
    return (Expression<Func<IHaveNoteRemarkSubject, bool>>) lambda;
}
```

You may notice that the method above doesn't do any NULL checking on the contains field.  The way DevForce will execute the query, it should work even if the field is NULL.  DevForce is smart about that kind of thing.  The only time (I think) that you would need explicit NULL logic is if you were going to compile this expression to a runnable delegate and then invoke it that way.  If you were to do that, you could just add an extra call to `PredicateBuilder.Make` to check for a null 'propertyName' value.

For more information on building dynamic filters (and even whole queries) in DevForce, check out their documentation  [Create dynamic "Where" clauses](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/dynamic-where), [Combine predicates with PredicateBuilder](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/predicatebuilder-methods) and [Build queries dynamically](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/dynamic-queries)